# Shifting elements in array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, shift

I am trying to shift elements in an array. I tried from the book but it does not seem to work.
The user types in how many to shift the array by in the main class, and then it gets sent into a shifter class into a shift method. Starting from array position [1].

This is what I have:

```
// Pos is the users entered for how many positions to shift
// data is the array of elements 1-length of data
// temp is place holder

public void shift(int pos)
{
    while(pos > 0)
    {
        int temp = data[data.length];

        for(int i = pos; i == data.length; i++ )
        {
            data[i+1] = data[i];
        }
        data[data.length] = temp;
        pos--;
    }   
}
```

Comment: int temp = data[data.length-1];

Comment: the part I am having trouble with is im suppose allow the user to input how many to shift the array by calling it variable (pos). But i cant find a spot to put it in. I can only get it to go through the array once

Comment: Put it in a continuous while loop that only gets broken with the right prompt.

Comment: Is this Java?  C++?  You need to tag your question with the name of the language you're using.

Comment: Not sure im doing it right. I am getting an outofbound exception

Comment: public void shift(int pos)
    {
       while(pos>0)
       {
          int temp = data[data.length];
       
          for(int i = pos; i == data.length; i++ )
          {
             data[i+1] = data[i];
          }
          data[data.length] = temp;
          pos--;
       }   
    }

Comment: are you doing a CIRCULAR and RIGHT shift from pos to end? First and foremost, for outofbound exception, data[data.length] and data[i+1] when i=data.length-1 these 2 expressions are the culprits.

Comment: Java indexes arrays starting at 0, so the data elements have indexes 0 through `length - 1`.  Are you sure that the comment "data is the array of elements 1-length of data" is correct?  Are you sure that you're supposed to start with `data[1]`, and that `data[0]` is supposed to stay untouched through the whole process?  Is this book a Java book, or are its examples in some other language where array indexes start at 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you are getting **ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException** is that your data array has a size of `data.length` (counting from 1), but you have tried to access the `data[data.length]` element in the last iteration of the loop which is `data.length+1` element of the array which doesn't exist and is out of bound of array, because of array index starting from 0 in Java.

Correct Code :-

```
// within your while loop
int temp=data[data.length-1];
for(int i=data.length-1;i>=1;i--)
{
  data[i] = data[i-1];
}
// decrease the position now
 data[0]=temp;
```

Kindly check the below link to know more about this Exception :-

[ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException---How to Handle](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/exceptions/java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-how-to-handle-array-index-out-of-bounds-exception/)

Comment: I paisted it in and it doesnt not like: int temp = data[data.length];

Comment: @Lightk3ira-But you added the same piece of code,check still your code.

Comment: @Lightk3ira, you need to do reverse iteration, else i+1 value will be overwritten by value at i eventually making everything same as the value at i. I don't think that's what you want do you?

Comment: Thanks for the downvote; I could find out the mistake in my code and fix the bug.

Answer (score 1):

Put it in a while loop with some sort of break command, in this example "quit"

```
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);  

boolean run = true;
while(run){
    System.out.println("What would you like to shift?");
    String input = br.readLine();

    if(input.equals("quit")) break;
    else{
        int pos = Integer.parseInt(input);
        int temp = data[pos];

        for(int i = pos; i<data.length-1; i++)  {
            data[i] = data[i+1];
        }
    }  
}
```

Of course you will need to do error checking on your input to make sure it is a valid position in the array. I am, however, posting this from a droid and coding on a phone is a pain.

This code also does a bit more than you are asking, but it gives an idea behind the logic of the while loop. Also, I just read your edit and I'm not sure I understand what exactly is going on, but again hope this may help. Would have put it as a comment but obviously it's a bit lengthy for that.

Answer (score 1):

```
int temp=data[data.length-1];
for(int i=data.length-1;i>=1;i--)
{
data[i+1] = data[i];
}
data[0]=temp;
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest solution:

```
private static void shiftArray(int[] array) {

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {

      int temp = array[i];
      array[i] = array[i + 1];
      array[i + 1] = temp;
    }

    for (int p : array)
      System.out.print(p +  " ");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to shift right and circularly, from 1 to end by `pos` positions this is what you can do:

```
public void shift(int pos) {

    while (pos-- > 0) {//shift 1 right for pos number of times

        //notice the data.length-1 for the last item. data.length as index would be out of bound.
        int tmp = data[data.length - 1];

        //start from the last and keep shifting the left one to current.
        for (int i = data.length - 1; i > 1; i--) {
            data[i] = data[i - 1];
        }

        //since it's a circular shift, last one (before shifting) will shift to 1 index.
        data[1] = tmp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late answer, but I think the easiest way is to se module like this:

```
int[] original = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
int[] reordered = new int[original.length];
int shift = 1;

for(int i=0; i<original.length;i++)
    reordered[i] = original[(shift+i)%original.length];
```